# SSIS fails to insert new document

Tags: ssis, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

good morning to all.

I'm currently working with some SSIS packages that upload new data from an Excel file to a CosmosDB Collection.

In some Collections it works just fine but in some other identical Collections SSIS fails and gives me this error message:

**"No Document ID specified. Please specify a ID when inserting data".**

I normally pass the id field as a GUID and that's enough, but in some cases the collection rejects the row, as if I'm not passing the id for the new row. I've tried to pass it as a regular string and as a GUID field, but neither of both work as it should.

I have also compared if there is any difference between the collections that work fine with the ID field and the collections that reject the row, having seen no difference whatsoever.

I really don't know where else could I look to fix this problem.

Comment: Can you post more details? What does the data in Excel look like? Are you sure the field is ID as it should be id. It also must be formatted as a string.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for replying. Gonna answer your questions in order

1) What does the data in Excel look like? -- Is just a bunch of personal information for new patients: names, address, phone number... nothing too special about it, all strings

2) Are you sure the field is ID as it should be id? -- Yes, the ID field is set as "ID FIELD" in the cosmos DB configuration and that's the one that takes GUID type values (as string, as you mentioned), and there's also the Partition Key which is the equivalent of a social security number.

Example -> "id": "5819a821-56fg-4i33-8245-rt90c0eqq42"

Comment: I just realized there is no connector for cosmos db. How are you connecting to Cosmos with SSIS?

Comment: With VS2019, you install DataTools for VS 2019, you also need to install the ODBC drivers for cosmosDB in your PC, you then create the ODBC connectors you need to get to your collections. After all of that is done, you can use SSIS to read and write data from CosmosDB

Comment: Ok. Then can you post the source code you use to insert data into Cosmos into your question?

Comment: That's the catch... as I mentioned, I'm working with a SSIS package, there's no coding involved. Instead, you work with the "boxes" to make connections, derived columns for data transformation, and most importantly, source and destination "boxes" which are the ones that read and write the data from a to the collections. Sadly I can't seem to post a print screen to be clearer...

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure I can help you here. SSIS + ODBC to Cosmos is a black box to me. If you are able to do this via another means I would look into it.

Comment: Thank you Mark for your time and for trying to help. Sadly, SSIS and CosmosDB is whole obscure world not many people know about... Looks like I gotta work this whole thing in a different manner.

Comment: People typically use Azure Data Factory to do this. It basically provides the same functionality. There are also tons of docs on this. here is the doc on how to use with Cosmos DB, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db and also here is a doc on the Excel connector, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-excel

Comment: I suggest in the first instance that you try using CSV (text) as a source, not xlsx. Excel has a way of corrupting data types. In fact.. excel definitely has an issue where it makes data NULL when it isn't. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/78b87712-8ffe-4c72-914b-f1c031ba6c75/excel-source-on-ssis-2008-brings-null-values-imex1-not-working?forum=sqlintegrationservices